# Add new column dynamically in table mySQL with Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a sensor list form in my program. There the user can do CRUD.
How do when the user enters new sensor data, the new data automatically creates a new column in the table in my database (automatically alter table)

```
public function store(Request $request){
   $data = new Mst_sensor();
   $arr = array_merge($arr, ['created_by' => Auth::user()->userid, 'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);
   $data->create($arr);
   

   $sensor= new Trs_sensor_d;
   $table = $sensor->getTable();
   $columns = \DB::getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing($table);
        
   $data_field = [];
   foreach ($columns as $k => $v) {
      $data_field[$k] = $v;
   }
   $removed = array_pop($data_field);
   $fix_data_field = end($data_field);

   $q = "ALTER TABLE `trs_raw_d_gpa` ADD `coba` VARCHAR(25) NULL AFTER '" . $fix_data_field . "'";
}
```

How can alter table run automatically???

Comment: If you're changing the schema in response to user input it suggests that your schema design is badly flawed.

Answer (score 0):

Think about how to design the database so that users cannot change the structure.
What you want to do is not recommended.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).